# how to make divs show properly in one line?

Tags: css, frontend

Hey I am trying to several divs in one line as a table headers. But when I make the window size smaller, some headers go to the next line.
How can I keep them in one line and shrink the whole divs size when needed?

Comment: can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) of your code

Comment: Try giving each Header element a width of 33% (if you have 3) or take a look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ which keeps growing popularity and is supported in the relevant browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `display: table-cell;` to keep the divs from flowing down the page. If you want them to resize then perhaps something like Bootstraps layout can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the width of your div's in either percent or vw.

Here, it will take up 20 percent of the parent div

```
.example_div {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Here it will take up 20 percent of the device width (which may be larger than parent width)

```
.example_div {
    width: 20vw;
}
```

You can use these in combination with max-width to allow larger screen to keep the initial width behavior you set, which I assume below is pixels.

Here, it will set a maximum width, but shrink by percent when it needs to.

```
.example_div {
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 20%;
}
```